# append data to constructor empty list variable in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I have one class. For that i want to append data to constructor empty list variable. I am trying to append data. But it's not working and throwing error as "NameError: name 'items' is not defined". before this code has been worked.

Here it my code snippet :

```
class data:
    def __init__(self,items=[]):
        self.items = items
        self.m1(n)
    def m1(self,n):
        self.n=2
        for i in range(self.n):
            d = input('enter the values :')
            self.items.append(d)
        print(self.items)
d=data(items)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here are some issues wrong:

1.) On line 11, items is not defined anywhere before trying to initialize the class, so you end up receiving an error when you call

```
 d=data(items)
```

2.) On line 4, n is not defined. It is neither passed in along as a parameter with the constructor or defined elsewhere within the constructor block. You will need to define n.

Here is a working version though, with all the variables properly defined:

```
class data:
    def __init__(self, n, items=[]):
        self.items = items
        self.m1(n)

    def m1(self, n):
        self.n=2
        for i in range(self.n):
            d = input('enter the values :')
            self.items.append(d)
        print(self.items)

items = [1, 5, 7]
d = data(2, items)
```

Comment: same error it showing.  previously my code has been worked. but now it's not working.

Comment: can you try again. I made some edits. The main issue is you need to already define items somewhere already before initializing **d**

`items = [1, 5, 7]`
`d = data(2, items)`

Comment: ok...thanks. it's working. but previously my code snippet is working. now it's not working. what's the issue for that code snippet.

Comment: the same things I highlighted in the answer above.  On line 11, items is not defined anywhere, in the constructor, n is not defined anywhere either.

Answer (score 0):

```
class data:
def __init__(self,number,name,list_values=[]):
    self.number = int(input('Enter a number :'))
    self.name = name
    self.list_values = list_values
    self.m1()
def m1(self):
    for i in range(self.number):
        items = input('Enter the values :')
        self.list_values.append(items)
    print(self.list_values)
list_values= None
d=data('siddarth',list_values)
```